Error Updating Using Pacman: 'failed to commit transaction (could not find or read package)'
Every time I run error sudo pacman -Syu  or yay. It always shows up
failed to commit transaction (could not find or read package)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
 -> error installing repo packages

Can't figure out how to fix this.
It should have updated all the packages

Is this for Msys2 or Archlinux? If the former -- then the question would be on-topic, If the latter, then this is an Arch distro issue and not directly programming related. That said, Arch pacman -Syu is working fine, so I suspect the issue you are having is related to the mirror you are using from /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist Quick check, just edit the mirrorlist file and comment out the first mirror so it tries from the 2nd, and so on... The error says "could not find or read package" -- so it receives a package name from the repo that cannot be found when it tries to download it.

sudo pacman -Syu --ignore gtest

The above command works for me. There seems to be problem with gtest and hence ignoring it lets the other packages to upgrade.

For me, the solution ended up being to clear out the files in /var/cache/pacman/pkg and re-attempting the pacman -Syu.
I don't know exactly which package caused the issue, but I had already tried updating my mirrors using Reflector, and also tried using pacman -Syyu to ensure that the repo metadata was re-downloaded. So, for me, the issue was not related to mirrors.
The error doesn't tell you which package could not be read, which seems like important information, but oh well.

As Erik said above, deleting files in /var/cache/pacman/pkg ;
as well as making sure your mirrors are based in the correct geographical location based on where you or your main VPN location(s) are based in, as incorrect configurations can sometimes cause timeouts.
